# Cross site iframes break in heroku deployment. Redux store possibly to blame?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, redux, react-redux

I have some iframe embeds in my react app that work fine locally but end up blank in heroku. They are all https soundcloud or youtube embeds and are rendered dynamically. No relevant errors pop up in my Heroku logs or in the network tab. The heroku logs and the network tab both show the exact same things yet oddly there is no mention of fetching the iframe embeds or loading them or anything. Interestingly enough I have set up various iframes on my page from soundcloud and youtube that work statically and when dynamically rendered, there is no cross site errors, no cors issues, they work exactly like they work when I deploy locally, and they all use the same embed url as the blank ones do. Even more strange is the fact that all other functionality of the app are completely unharmed by the deployment to heroku. I can add and substract entries from the database and fetch them aswell. These operations all require some cross site trickery and various other hacks which all work fine even on heroku. It's just the iframes loaded from my database objects that seem to break when deployed on heroku but not when deployed locally.

I understand that all of this is just up in the air without any code or images so I will try and clarify as best as possible with screenshots and the source of the app as well, So we can rule out some possibilities.

The main structure for the display of iframes is like so:

1. Backend server connects to mongodb database
2. Mongodb feeds the urls of the embeds to the application
3. Redux takes the database information and adds it to it's store, which it gives to the react frontend
4. React frontend takes the the database info and sends them down the component line as props until eventually reaching a component called "Embed.js"
5. This embed component is simply an iframe with a bit javascript where the "src" parameter is, this javascript does the last few modifications to the url property of the data from the database, making it into a proper embed url.
6. The iframe works and shows up with the proper embed.

Now this all works well locally but in heroku one of these parts clearly breaks and gives a blank element.

From deduction and troubleshooting I know that the backend connects to the database (positive log that confirms this), I know that the database can properly feed data to the backend from server logs and other functionality working, I know that the react frontend works and all the props are valid as seen locally, I know the embed component works fine from troubleshooting and local production. So the only problem left is the redux store... and when I check the devtools on the heroku app it says the store is not found.

So I am fairly confident this is the problem, something with the deployment to heroku breaks my redux store and all the iframes don't get the necessary information. Which is why they are blank.

Here is the code for my redux store:

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, /* preloadedState, */
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    )

);

export default store
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am not sure where to really start with this problem and have yet to find any other questions like it. It's possible the store has nothing to do with it and I am mistaken.

Edit 1:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Container} from "reactstrap";
// const videoUrlToID = /(?<=v=).*/
const videoUrlToID = /(?<=v=).{11}(?!list)/

export class Embed extends Component {

    makeEmbed = (url) => {

        if (url.match(/soundcloud/) === "soundcloud") {
            let Video = "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&url=" + url + "&auto_play=true&show_artwork=true"
            return Video;
        }

        if (url.match(/youtube/) === "youtube") {
            let videoID = url.match(videoUrlToID)
            let Video = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?autoplay=1" + "&rel=0" + "&vq=144p"
            return Video;
        }

    }

    render() {

        if (this.props.isOpen === true) return (

            <Container>
                {/* This works */}
                <iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" loading="eager" importance="high" src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.props.item.url.match(/(?<=v=).{11}(?!list)/) + "?autoplay=1" + "&rel=0" + "&vq=144p"}/>
                {/* This does not work in heroku */}
                <iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" loading="eager" importance="high" src={this.makeEmbed(this.props.item.url)}/>
            </Container>

        )

        else return null;

    }

}

// PropTypes
Embed.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    next: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Embed;
```

The first iframe works. The second iframe works only locally and not in heroku!

Edit final:

```js
<iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" loading="eager" importance="high" src={((this.props.item.url.match(/soundcloud/)) ? "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&url=" + this.props.item.url + "&auto_play=true&show_artwork=true" : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.props.item.url.match(/(?<=v=).{11}(?!list)/) + "?autoplay=1" + "&rel=0" + "&vq=144p")}/>
```

Solution: Use inline ternary operator to circumvent react function breaking in Heroku.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to just comment, so here is my comment: Try checking the Network to be sure the request is coming through from the backend, with data. You could also check if data is coming through by rendering something else if the frame url is missing. Do you have a link to the app?

Comment: It is possible that there is a CORS issue and instead of complaining it just doesn't send the data thru.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I think I have already checked the network tab but I will check again, your idea for sending in other non cross site data is something I haven't considered and will try. My biggest fear is that it's a cors issue, but I don't really see how that would happen if locally it isn't a cors issue.

Comment: @TomKing Ok I have done some more thorough testing based on your advice. It doesn't seem like a redux problem anymore more like a react problem. I will post the code in the question that relates to the problem. It seems like everything breaks in my "makeEmbed" function which generated a embedding url from the items url. It's kinda difficult to explain in text so I will just edit the code in. I will continue to test it and try things but I am honestly quite perplexed by this.

Comment: Ok final edit for now. It seems the problem really was somewhere in my "makeEmbed" function which for some odd reason breaks in heroku but not locally. It's quite the mystery why such a simple function with and if and some regex would somehow break when deployed. Regardless I fixed it by simply using an inline ternary operator which looks cleaner anyways. I will post another question specifically relating to the heroku/function failure later. @TomKing Thank you very much for the insight and approach, it means a lot to me, and hopefully many others with this problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out!